# Is using memory mapped files possible/worthwhile for writing/reading protocol buffers?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I am using a `FileOutputStream` instance (wrapped by a `CodedOutputStream` object) to write my protocol buffers output.

I am wondering whether it is possible to use memory mapped files instead and whether doing so would yield a noteworthy performance improvement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to implement this but you'll not likely see any perf gains.  In the scenario you describe, the only difference between using the stream object and a file mapping is which subsystem is performing the I/O (initiating reads/writes).  For file mappings, the memory manager handles generating page faults for read operations, and will persist dirty (written) pages at it's leisure.

For serializing protocol buffers, good old fashioned stream based file I/O is the simplest, most portable solution.